# Nvidia driver update, now nvidia-smi doesn't work

Tags: drivers, nvidia

So I used:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

and before this nvidia-smi returned:

```
    Thu Aug 24 22:07:42 2017       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 375.66                 Driver Version: 375.66                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla M2050         Off  | 0000:05:00.0     Off |                    0 |
| N/A   N/A   P12    N/A /  N/A |     47MiB /  2622MiB |      5%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1910    G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                              31MiB |
|    0      2207    G   compiz                                          15MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now it returns:

```
Failed to initialize NVML: Driver/library version mismatch
```

I assume the drivers it installed are incompatible, and I would like to revert to the older drivers I was using.

Here is the log after the ubuntu-drivers command:

```
    Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libcublas7.5 libcudart7.5 libcufft7.5 libcufftw7.5 libcurand7.5 libcusolver7.5 libcusparse7.5 libdrm-dev
  libgl1-mesa-dev libnppc7.5 libnppi7.5 libnpps7.5 libnvblas7.5 libnvrtc7.5 libnvtoolsext1 libnvvm3
  libpthread-stubs0-dev libthrust-dev libvdpau-dev libx11-dev libx11-doc libx11-xcb-dev libxau-dev libxcb-dri2-0-dev
  libxcb-dri3-dev libxcb-glx0-dev libxcb-present-dev libxcb-randr0-dev libxcb-render0-dev libxcb-shape0-dev
  libxcb-sync-dev libxcb-xfixes0-dev libxcb1-dev libxdamage-dev libxdmcp-dev libxext-dev libxfixes-dev libxshmfence-dev
  libxxf86vm-dev linux-headers-4.4.0-72 linux-headers-4.4.0-72-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-75
  linux-headers-4.4.0-75-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-78 linux-headers-4.4.0-78-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-79
  linux-headers-4.4.0-79-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-81 linux-headers-4.4.0-81-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-83
  linux-headers-4.4.0-83-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-87 linux-headers-4.4.0-87-generic linux-image-4.4.0-72-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-75-generic linux-image-4.4.0-78-generic linux-image-4.4.0-79-generic linux-image-4.4.0-81-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-83-generic linux-image-4.4.0-87-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-72-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-75-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-78-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-79-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-81-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-83-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-87-generic
  mesa-common-dev nvidia-cuda-doc nvidia-cuda-gdb nvidia-opencl-dev opencl-headers x11proto-core-dev x11proto-damage-dev
  x11proto-dri2-dev x11proto-fixes-dev x11proto-gl-dev x11proto-input-dev x11proto-kb-dev x11proto-xext-dev
  x11proto-xf86vidmode-dev xorg-sgml-doctools xtrans-dev
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  iucode-tool
Recommended packages:
  libcuda1-384 nvidia-opencl-icd-384
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libcuda1-375 libcuinj64-7.5 nvidia-375 nvidia-cuda-dev nvidia-cuda-toolkit nvidia-opencl-icd-375 nvidia-profiler
  nvidia-visual-profiler
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  intel-microcode iucode-tool nvidia-384
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 8 to remove and 126 not upgraded.
Need to get 74.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 680 MB disk space will be freed.
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted amd64 iucode-tool amd64 1.5.1-1ubuntu0.1 [33.8 kB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted amd64 intel-microcode amd64 3.20170707.1~ubuntu16.04.0 [985 kB]
Get:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 nvidia-384 amd64 384.69-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1 [73.0 MB]
Fetched 74.0 MB in 20s (3,597 kB/s)                                                                                      
(Reading database ... 519338 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing nvidia-cuda-toolkit (7.5.18-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing nvidia-cuda-dev (7.5.18-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing nvidia-visual-profiler (7.5.18-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing nvidia-profiler (7.5.18-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libcuinj64-7.5:amd64 (7.5.18-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libcuda1-375 (375.66-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Removing nvidia-opencl-icd-375 (375.66-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Removing nvidia-375 (375.66-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Removing all DKMS Modules
Done.
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-375-prime/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf (x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-375-prime/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_EGL.conf (x86_64-linux-gnu_egl_conf) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-375-prime/alt_ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_GL.conf (i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-375-prime/alt_ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_EGL.conf (i386-linux-gnu_egl_conf) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf (x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa-egl/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_EGL.conf (x86_64-linux-gnu_egl_conf) in auto mode
INFO:Disable nvidia-375
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.8) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-92-generic
W: mdadm: /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf defines no arrays.
Selecting previously unselected package iucode-tool.
(Reading database ... 515566 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../iucode-tool_1.5.1-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking iucode-tool (1.5.1-1ubuntu0.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-384.
Preparing to unpack .../nvidia-384_384.69-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-384 (384.69-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package intel-microcode.
Preparing to unpack .../intel-microcode_3.20170707.1~ubuntu16.04.0_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking intel-microcode (3.20170707.1~ubuntu16.04.0) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Setting up iucode-tool (1.5.1-1ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up nvidia-384 (384.69-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-384/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf (x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-384/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_EGL.conf (x86_64-linux-gnu_egl_conf) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-384/alt_ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_GL.conf (i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-384/alt_ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_EGL.conf (i386-linux-gnu_egl_conf) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/share/nvidia-384/glamor.conf to provide /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/glamoregl.conf (glamor_conf) in auto mode
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
INFO:Enable nvidia-384
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
Adding system user `nvidia-persistenced' (UID 124) ...
Adding new group `nvidia-persistenced' (GID 130) ...
Adding new user `nvidia-persistenced' (UID 124) with group `nvidia-persistenced' ...
Not creating home directory `/'.
Loading new nvidia-384-384.69 DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 4.4.0-92-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 4.4.0-92-generic
Done.

nvidia_384:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.4.0-92-generic/updates/dkms/

nvidia_384_modeset.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.4.0-92-generic/updates/dkms/

nvidia_384_drm.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.4.0-92-generic/updates/dkms/

nvidia_384_uvm.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.4.0-92-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod....

DKMS: install completed.
Setting up intel-microcode (3.20170707.1~ubuntu16.04.0) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
intel-microcode: microcode will be updated at next boot
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.8) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-92-generic
W: mdadm: /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf defines no arrays.
```

It looks like I had been using driver version 375? But I tried

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-375
```

And it didn't help.

I would be really grateful if someone could explain how to do it in painful detail because I'm pretty new to linux. Thanks a ton in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try purging everything with nvidia from your packages and reinstall it clean. You can use aptitude to find everything installed or corrupted.

If you don't have it installed yet.

```
sudo apt install aptitude
sudo aptitude search nvidia | grep -E "^i|^c"
```

Then purge the packages it finds, reinstall afterwards and you should be good.